# How does node.js know where I placed the script?

Tags: node.js

I've tried the most recepies for making a "hello world" example in node.js to work. I have tried both on mac and now windows. With no luck.

1. I install the node.msi
2. run cmd.exe
3. I type: `node` in command shell, then enter.
4. A new line appear with `>` sign , so now I assume I'm in "node mode"
5. I type : `node test.js`,
   the content in test.js is `console.log.("hello")`, then I press enter
6. three dots "..." appear in the output.

In similar tutorials the expected output is a string "hello", I just get `...` And I dont know what `...` signifies. Does it imply a server is running?

I run cmd.exe as administrator. The `...` output is similar when I tested on a mac btw.
I also do not understand how I just can reference the js script without a full path. How does node know where i placed the script?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to use node. You can use it as a REPL like you discovered by simply typing "node" into the command line and then you can issue commands in a linear format. However, the most common way to run node, and the way that you are missing, is to run a file containing your javascript directly from the command line.

So, from a clean command line without entering the Node REPL, simply type "node test.js" and you will have the expected "Hello World" output. Node looks for the script in the current directory. You will need to provide a relative or absolute path if the file resides elsewhere. Think of node as being no different then running any standard Unix/Linux command like "cp" or "ls"

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just adding one or two things to what was said before.

A moment ago I was stuck with the same problem (getting started with **node.js** in **Windows 7**, I was trying to open files and all I've seen were three dots - "...") and I've discovered that you can easily load scripts in node REPL by simply writing:

`.load yourFileName.js` 
in node terminal REPL.

When the js script that I wanted to load was not in default node folder, I had to add relative path to it. So if file is in folder node/node_modules/example.js on your computer you have to write:

```
.load node_modules/example.js
```

I've discovered that by simply typing `.help` in node.

This just supplements the answer above which is otherwise perfectly valid.